# laravel 5.3 Many-to-Many relationship returns associated Role only when queried

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am just confused on how this thing is working .

I have a M-M relationship between by Users and Roles. If I retrieve my user like the following :-

```
 $user = Auth::User();//->with('roles')->get();

        $roleName = $user->roles[0]->name;

        return $this->sendResponse('User retrieved successfully',$user);
```

I get the following response :

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "User retrieved successfully",
  "data": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "dummy",
    "email": "dummy@dummy.com",
    "created_at": "2017-05-06 09:49:50",
    "updated_at": "2017-05-06 09:49:50",
    "tenant_id": 2,
    "roles": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "created_at": "2017-05-06 06:26:55",
        "updated_at": "2017-05-06 06:26:55",
        "name": "Admin",
        "permissions": null,
        "pivot": {
          "user_id": 2,
          "role_id": 1
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But, if I retrieve my user as :-

```
$user = Auth::User();//->with('roles')->get();



        return $this->sendResponse('User retrieved successfully',$user);
```

I get the following resut :-

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "User retrieved successfully",
  "data": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ali",
    "email": "ali@and-or.com",
    "created_at": "2017-05-06 09:49:50",
    "updated_at": "2017-05-06 09:49:50",
    "tenant_id": 2
  }
}
```

Why is this happening ? I expected the "first" posted result to the latter query.

Secondly, I did not modify the $user after the query in the first "method" how did it get its Roles attachment ?

I am sure there is an explanation, but I couldn't put my finger on it.

Comment: because in first with `Auth::User()->roles[0]->name` you are also returning the relation. whereas only `Auth::User();` in second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When retrieving a model, the `User` in this instance, relationships are not automatically also retrieved (Since on the database side this would require a second query while you might not even need the `roles` in a certain situation).

In your first example, by accessing the roles through `$roleName = $user->roles[0]->name;`, Laravel does the `roles()` query automatically, and also adds the roles object to the `User` (So it can be accessed again at a later point without needing to redo the query). This explains why the roles are 'magically' attached to your `User` model in the first example.

In your second example this query is not done automatically, so you do not get the `roles` relation in your response.

If you want to have access to the `User`s roles, then you could use the `with()` method like in your comment to eager load the relationship, but keep in mind that this implies doing the second query in order to get this data from the database.

Another option, if you *always* want the `User` model to have its `Roles` attached, would be to add `roles` to the `$appends` array of the model:

```
protected $appends = ['roles'];
```

This tells Laravel that the `roles` attribute is one which you always want available on your model, and it then does what is necessary to make this happen (In this case, query the relationship).

Comment: Thank you. But I did try the "with()" approach as can be seen that it has been commented. Because instead of retrieving specific User and its Role , it would 'somehow' retrieve all the users with attached roles. I am not sure why.

Comment: Although I'm not sure why, threads like [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/trying-to-eager-load-prefs-and-perms-to-authuser-for-all-views) also report the problem that all users are returned. However, you can also load relations after obtaining the original result by calling `$user->load('roles');`. This should not sacrifice efficiency, since you are only working on a single model so don't have an N+1 problem to worry about.